# Vectorized matrix manhattan distance in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to implement an efficient vectorized `numpy` to make a Manhattan distance matrix. I'm familiar with the construct used to create an efficient Euclidean distance matrix using dot products as follows:

```
A = [[1, 2]   
     [2, 1]]

B = [[1, 1],
     [2, 2],
     [1, 3],
     [1, 4]]

def euclidean_distmtx(X, X):
    f = -2 * np.dot(X, Y.T)
    xsq = np.power(X, 2).sum(axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
    ysq = np.power(Y, 2).sum(axis=1)
    return np.sqrt(xsq + f + ysq)
```

I want to implement somthing similar but using Manhattan distance instead. So far I've got close but fell short trying to rearrange the absolute differences. As I understand it, the Manhattan distance is

[image: \sum_i |x_i - y_i| = |x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2| + ...]

I tried to solve this by considering if the absolute function didn't apply at all giving me this equivalence

[image: \sum_i x_i - y_i = \sum_i x_i - \sum_i y_i]

which gives me the following vectorization

```
def manhattan_distmtx(X, Y):
    f = np.dot(X.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1), Y.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1).T)
    return f / Y.sum(axis=1) - Y.sum(axis=1)
```

I think I'm the right track but I just can't move the values around without removing that absolute function around the difference between each vector elements. I'm sure there's a clever trick around the absolute values, possibly by using `np.sqrt` of a squared value or something but I can't seem to realize it.

Comment: Manhattan distance is not related to dot products, so anything with `.dot` is not going to be of much help.

Comment: You could also try e_dist  and just leave out the sqrt section towards the bottom.  this einsum approach can be used in a variety of situations as a substitute for scipy cdist and pdist etc.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660459/how-do-i-find-the-distances-between-two-points-from-different-numpy-arrays/42662151#42662151

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think we can leverage BLAS based matrix-multiplication here, as there's no element-wise multiplication involved here. But, we have few alternatives.

**Approach #1**

We can use [Scipy's `cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) that features the Manhattan distance with its optional metric argument set as `'cityblock'` -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

out = cdist(A, B, metric='cityblock')
```

**Approach #2 - A**

We can also leverage `broadcasting`, but with more memory requirements -

```
np.abs(A[:,None] - B).sum(-1)
```

**Approach #2 - B**

That could be re-written to use less memory with slicing and summations for input arrays with two cols -

```
np.abs(A[:,0,None] - B[:,0]) + np.abs(A[:,1,None] - B[:,1])
```

**Approach #2 - C**

Porting over the `broadcasting` version to make use of faster `absolute` computation with [`numexpr` module](http://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#how-it-works) -

```
import numexpr as ne
A3D = A[:,None]
out = ne.evaluate('sum(abs(A3D-B),2)')
```

Comment: Very comprehensive! I believe approach 2B needs to iterate over all columns. According to `timeit`, `scipy` is the fastest. Approach C just looks ugly ;)

EDIT: typo