# Distance with array of different sizes

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array with dimensions as such:

```
pos = np.array([[   1.72,   2.56],
            [   0.24,   5.67],
            [  -1.24,   5.45],
            [  -3.17,  -0.23],
            [   1.17,  -1.23],
            [   1.12,   1.08]])
```

and I want to find the distance between each line of the array to an index point which would be

```
ref = np.array([1.22, 1.18])
```

I would thus have an array with 4 elements as an answer but I'm really confused as to the method of approaching this with only numpy as I've tried many ways yet the size of the ref array presents a challenge. Thanks for the help.

The expected answer is an array with 6 elements.  The elements are approximately:

```
[ 1.468,  4.596,  4.928 ,  4.611,  2.410,  0.141 ]
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50263748/edit) to include your desired output and tell us the calculation for "distance between each line"?

Comment: The array size isn't the issue... there are similar solutions some using scipy's cdist others using einsum for example.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660459/how-do-i-find-the-distances-between-two-points-from-different-numpy-arrays/42662151#42662151

Comment: I've edited the question, I have tried that but I Keep getting this error somehow, "raise ValueError('XB must be a 2-dimensional array.')"

Comment: @HumanError I wonder if you _ever_ accept any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy` and assuming Euclidean metric:

```
import numpy as np
np.linalg.norm(pos - ref, axis=1)
```

If you need a Python list (instead of `numpy` array), add `.tolist()` to the previous line:

```
np.linalg.norm(pos - ref, axis=1).tolist()
```